# How to copy binary file with x64dbg\x32dbg after it changed it self

Tags: x64dbg

I know how to do it with OllyDbg but with [x64dbg\x32dbg](https://x64dbg.com/#start) I don't know how to do it.

I have a packed binary file and at some point it unpacks itself and I found the point where it does it.
I want to copy it to a binary file at this point (after unpacked).

I tried using right click on the code and use `Copy` and `Binary` but I don't see any option to copy to executable:
[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: There is no such function in x64dbg. I have no idea why but it is a no-brainer.
Scylla does not work. Just try to debug calc.exe and write a dump with Scylla. No chance ! It's like someone has build a car but forgot to create doors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to dump the executable. You can use Scylla (which is built into x64dbg) to dump and restore the executable.

You can find Scylla in `Plugins -> Scylla`